Locators in Selenium: XPath for span class
Here below is span class, could you people can help me with locators values of below span class:
<span class="close_servey_close sec_popup exist_intent_close material -icons">
::before ==$0
"close"
</span>

I'm using below locators but it's not working,
//DIV[@id='survey_popup']/descendant::SPAN[contains(.,'close')]


Can you share the URL of the app if it's public?

What does, "it's not working" mean? Is it throwing an error? If so, edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted. Have you checked to see if the element is in an IFRAME or shadow-root?

Without code or more info, only can help with this XPATH
"//span[contains(@class, 'close_servey_close')]"

and click it I supose is what you want
